Does Transcoder API provides SRT or RTMP to HLS/m3u8 transcoding?
Looking for on-cloud solution (Google Transcode API) for Transcoding an RTMP/SRT to HLS/m3u8.
Currrently I am using FFMpeg for the same but encoding parameters peaks the CPU.
Tried FFMpeg but the encoding parameter peaks the CPU
